# Custom Post Type archive-{post-type}.php not working

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

My permalink is set to a custom structure: /blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

I have a custom post type we'll call "post-type". I also have an archive page named archive-post-type.php

Accessing domain.com/post-type/ though is defaulting to archive.php and skipping archive-post-type.php

My register_post_type looks like this:

```
    register_post_type( 'ch_post_type',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            .......
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => 'post-type',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_position' => 100,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-category',
    'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields'),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'post-type', 'with_front' => false ),
    'hierarchical' => true
    )
);
```

Under Settings > Reading, I have a Page set up for Home and Blog.

I've flushed my permalinks as well.

I know others have had this problem and I have not yet seen an answer that solves it. I'm on version 3.9

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Apart from the answer, I would not use underscores in the post type name. Rather just use normal hypens.

Answer (score 3):

Try making your `has_archive` set to just boolean `true`.

Comment: Thanks, man. I realized how irrelevant that extra info I gave.